# Can't change NODE_ENV to other value beside production

Tags: node.js, docker

I've tried passing NODE_ENV as an argument

```
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
```

I tried passing it as an environment variable on my docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=development
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

Nothing works, inside my program, its value is "production"

My Dockerfile is based on `node:18-slim`, there is nothing special on it.

Complete example

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-slim AS base

FROM base AS build
WORKDIR /opt
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN npm run prisma:generate

FROM base
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends gettext-base supervisor nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY --from=build /opt/node_modules node_modules
COPY --from=build /opt/dist .

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV ${NODE_ENV}

ARG PORT=3000
ENV PORT $PORT
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-development}
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://docker:docker@postgres:5432/oidc?schema=public
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
  redis:
    image: redis:7
    tmpfs:
      - /data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "redis-cli ping | grep PONG"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      start_period: 5s
      retries: 3
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.3
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready --dbname $$POSTGRES_DB --username $$POSTGRES_USER"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      start_period: 5s
      retries: 3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
      POSTGRES_USER: docker
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
      POSTGRES_DB: oidc
```

If I build without docker compose, it works.

docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.15.1

docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.15.1

docker version

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.31
 Version:           20.10.23
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.10
 Git commit:        7155243
 Built:             Thu Jan 19 17:35:19 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.17.0 (99724)
 Engine:
  Version:          22.06.0-beta.0-926-g914b02ebaf.m
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.4
  Git commit:       914b02ebaf
  Built:            Thu Feb  9 12:31:06 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.18
  GitCommit:        2456e983eb9e37e47538f59ea18f2043c9a73640
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I read somewhere else, that docker-compose never overwrites the environment variables from the base image. Is it because of that? My base image is a node

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is that `DOCKER_ENV` there on purpose? How are you checking the value in your program?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the question, it is NODE_ENV

Comment: Again, how are you checking the value in your program? Can you reproduce this if you change the command you're running in the container to `node -e 'console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)'`?

Comment: Do you have a more complete example showing what happens in this Dockerfile?  (Is a multi-stage build involved?)

Comment: I've updated it. I read somewhere else that docker-compose never overwrites the environment variables from the base image. Is it because of that? My base image is a node

Comment: @AKX the output is production, no matter which value I put on it

Comment: What commands are you running to boot those containers?

Comment: I'm using the supervisor, because it is a sidecar container

Comment: You mention in your question that when running the app just with docker it is working properly, with the same `Dockerfile`? Please, could you include in your question information about your `nginx` and `supervisor` configuration files?

Comment: @jccampanero nginx or supervisor is irrelevant here. They don't make use of any env. variable, what matter is what I get on `RUN printenv` inside Docker

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Rodrigo. I asked because I think that the provided `Dockerfile` shouldn't work neither. Does it work as presented in the question? Please, where do you run `printenv`? Can you update your `Dockerfile` with that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem could be related, not to `docker-compose`, but actually to the way the application is being deployed.

In the first stage of your `Dockerfile` you are building your `node` or SPA application.

In the next stage you are exposing the result of that build (by the way, probably you can safely don't copy the `node_modules` directory to the final image) through `nginx` and `supervisor`. But please, be aware that neither `nginx` nor `supervisor` have knowledge about the `NODE_ENV` variable: that variable is only managed at runtime when the application is served with `node`, not `nginx`(sorry if I am missing something at this point, this is why I asked you about the `nginx` and `supervisor` configuration, I am not aware if in any way you are proxying `node`, I hope you get the point).

In order to make this variable visible to the application you probably will need to tweak the build process, or trying providing a helper script. Please, consider read for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57752046/how-to-set-node-env-variables-runtime-after-build-the-react-project) or [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679430/how-to-work-with-process-env-with-a-build-node-js-app-running-in-nginx) related SO questions, or [this great post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer [docker-compose build environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429984/docker-compose-build-environment-variable)

Are you setting the variable in your docker file? Something like:

```
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV
```

Comment: Is your build expecting the node_env variable be set? Did you try move the variable definition before run build in your Dockerfile. See the accepted answer in the link I posted.

Comment: Yes. We have conditionals for when it is running in dev or prod